# Python code to node.js

Tags: node.js, type-conversion

I found this part in a python code:

```
score = random.randint(0, 100)
filled_progbar = round(score / 100 * 10)
counter_ = '█' * filled_progbar + '‍ ‍' * (10 - filled_progbar)
```

It looks good in python but I don't know how I can put this in node.js.
Why I need this from python to node.js?
Because I am dumb to python and I am newbie in the node.js and therefore I am asking here. :)

Sorry if I didn't choose the right tags but I am not sure which tag would be good to this.

---

If my research is correct then the score part would be so:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

But I don't know the other part.

Comment: you can use `counter_ = '█'.repeat(filled_progbar) + '‍ ‍'.repeat(10 - filled_progbar)`

Comment: Hmm it seems that I need define somehow the **round** part because it is undefined and after I can use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pointless but fun so I gave it a go,

```
const score = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
const filled_progbar = Math.round(score/10.0);
const counter_ = '█'.repeat(filled_progbar) + '‍ ‍'.repeat(10 - filled_progbar)
console.log(counter_);
```